# File Name comparision in Bash

Tags: bash

I have two files containing list of files. I need to check what files are missing in the list of second file. Problem is that I do not have to match full name, but only need to match last 19 Characters of the file names.

E.g

MyFile123432**20150510230000.xlsx**

and

MyFile999996**20150510230000.xlsx**

are same files.

This is a unique problem and I don't know how to start. Kindly help.

Comment: Are your file names always exactly 31 characters long, so you need to compare characters 13 - 31?

Comment: Yes, file names are always 31 character long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk based solution:

```
$ awk '
   {start=length($0) - 18;}
   NR==FNR{a[substr($0, start)]++; next;} #save last 19 characters for every line in file2
   {if(!a[substr($0, start)]) print $0;} #If that is not present in file1, print that line.
'  file2.list file.list
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can use `comm` to match the exact file names and obtain a list of files not matchig. Then you can use [agrep](http://www.tgries.de/agrep/). I've never used it, but you might find it useful.

Or, as last option, you can do a brute force and for every line in the first file search into the second:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Iterate through the first file
while read LINE; do

    # Find the section of the filename that has to match in the other file
    CHECK_SECTION="$(echo "$LINE" | sed -nre 's/^.*([0-9]{14})\.(.*)$/\1.\2/p')"

    # Create a regex to match the filenames in the second file
    SEARCH_REGEX="^.*$CHECK_SECTION$"

    # Search...
    egrep "$SEARCH_REGEX" inputFile_2.txt

done < inputFile_1.txt
```

Here I assumed the filenames end with 14 digits that must match in the other file and a file extension that can be different from file to file but that has to match too:

```
MyFile12343220150510230000.xlsx
|  variable |   14digits |.ext
```

Comment: This solution looks like it's O(n*m)--I guess this is what you mean by "brute force".

Comment: Yes :D I'm aware of it, but the file is not too big it's not a big deal

Answer (score 0):

So, if the first file is `FILE1` and the second file is `FILE2` then if the intention is only to identify the files in `FILE2` that don't exist in `FILE1`, the following should do:

```
tmp1=$(mktemp)
tmp2=$(mktemp)
cat $FILE1 | rev | cut -c -19 | sort | uniq > ${tmp1}
cat $FILE2 | rev | cut -c -19 | sort | uniq > ${tmp2}
diff ${tmp1} ${tmp2} | rev
rm ${tmp1} ${tmp2}
```

In a nutshell, this reverses the characters on each line, and extracts the part you're interested in, saving to a temporary file, for each list of files.  The reversal of characters is done since you haven't said whether or not the length of filenames is guaranteed to be constant---the only thing we can rely on here is that the last 19 characters are of a fixed format (in this case, although the format is easily inferred, it isn't really relevant). The sort is important in order for the `diff` to show you what's not in the second file that *is* in the first.

If you're certain that there will only ever be files missing from `FILE2` and not the other way around (that is, files in `FILE2` that don't exist in `FILE1`), then you can clean things up by removing the cruft introduced by `diff`, so the last line becomes:

```
diff ${tmp1} ${tmp2} | rev | grep -i xlsx | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+.*//'
```

The `grep` limits the output to those lines with `xlsx` filenames, and the sed removes everything on a line from the first space encountered onwards.

Of course, technically this only tells you what *time-stamped-grouped* groups of files exist in `FILE1` but not `FILE2`--as I understand it, this is what you're looking for (my understanding of your problem description is that `MyFile12343220150510230000.xlsx` and `MyFile99999620150510230000.xlsx` would have identical content).  If the file names are always the same length (as you subsequently affirmed), then there's no need for the `rev`'s and the cut commands can just be amended to refer to fixed character positions.

In any case, to get the final list of files, you'll have to use the "cleaned up" output to filter the content of `FILE1`; so, modifying the script above so that it includes the "cleanup" command, we can filter the files that you need using a `grep`--the whole script then becomes:

```
tmp1=$(mktemp)
tmp2=$(mktemp)
missing=$(mktemp)
cat $FILE1 | rev | cut -c -19 | sort | uniq > ${tmp1}
cat $FILE2 | rev | cut -c -19 | sort | uniq > ${tmp2}
diff ${tmp1} ${tmp2} | rev | grep -i xlsx | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+.*//' > ${missing}
grep -E "("`echo $(<${missing}) | sed 's/[[:space:]]/|/g'`")" ${tmp1}  
rm ${tmp1} ${tmp2} ${missing}
```

The extended `grep` command (`-E`) just builds up an "or" regular expression for each timestamp-plus-extension and applies it to the first file.  Of course, this is all assuming that there will never be timestamp-groups that exist in `FILE2` and not in `FILE1`--if this *is* the case, then the "diff output processing" bit needs to be a little more clever.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use your standard `coreutil` tools:

```
for i in $(cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq -u); do 
    grep -q "$i" f1.txt && \
    echo "f2 missing '$i'" || \
    echo "f1 missing '$i'"
done
```

It will identify which non-common entries are missing from which file. You can also manipulate the non-common filenames in any way you like, e.g. parameter expansion/substring extraction, substring removal, or character indexes.